# ejs-multiselect want to set custom text on check box select syncfusion

Tags: syncfusion

i want to set text like 1 item selected, no item selected, when i selected check box, instead of showing selected check box text i want to show my text

function loadDataForPost() {

```
        const titleDropDown = document.getElementById("titleDropDown")["ej2_instances"][0];

        const selectedTitleId = titleDropDown.value;
        titleDropDown.text="test"

        const selectedTitleIdCsv = selectedTitleId.join(",");
      
        $("#hiddenTitleId").val(selectedTitleIdCsv);

    }
```